# Scaling the range of a variable - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, range, scaling

I have a variable, `1xn` double containing consecutive years

```
YEARS = 1900 1901 1902 1903 1904 1905 1906 1907 1908
```

Is there somehow any function able to perform a scaling of this variable as follows, listing just the starting date and the ending date in a string:

```
YEARS = 1900 - 1908
```

Comment: So you are expecting the output `8`? Don't understand your question.

Comment: what is the type of your data? A cell array of strings? I don't understand

Comment: @ Daniel & Benoit_11 - I have updated my question with some more information.

Comment: @steve It's still unclear.

Comment: What exactly do you expect as an output? Two (double) numbers, `1900` and `1908`? Or the string output `"1900 - 1908"`?

Comment: @ hdaberts - Having a string output "1900 -1908" is a must!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
YEARS = [1900 1901 1902 1903 1904 1905 1906 1907 1908];
A = min(YEARS); % Get the minimum value
B = max(YEARS); % Get the maximum value
formatStr = '%d - %d'; % Specify the string format
years = sprintf(formatStr,A,B); % Output the result
```

You might actually directly set `years = sprintf('%d - %d',min(YEARS),max(YEARS));` but that's less readable in my opinion.

Comment: @ A. Visser - Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

It is unclear what you expect. If it's consecutive, try `YEARS = [YEARS(1), Years(end)]`

Comment: That's not a string but a 1x2 double.